# Is there an Amadeus Self Service API for Historical Flight Offers Search?

Tags: amadeus

I want to access historical flight price offers data in the same way that the flight-offers-search api currently provides the same information for forward looking dates.

I'm looking at https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference but it looks like this endpoint is built for forward looking departure dates. When attempting to pass in a gone-past departure date I get an error in the request payload saying 'Date/Time is in the past'.

The only other offering I can see for historical prices is https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-price-analysis/api-reference but this is only provides historical prices in a quartile distribution based on booking data from 2019 which is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API in the Amadeus for Developers Self-Service APIs [catalogue](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air).